# restructuredtext: use directives for metadata

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I'm writing a simple webpage generator based on restructuredtext and I'd like to put tags into the document, like this.

```
=====
Title
=====

:author: Me
:tags: foo, bar

Here we go ...
```

What I want now:

- get in possession of some kind of document tree
- find the `tags` entry, read it, process it (like print the tags on the command line), remove it and render the remaining tree.

So I'd like to write compatible restructuredtext in case it's being compiled with something different than my program.

Can someone give me a hint? I found this one here http://svn.python.org/projects/external/docutils-0.6/docutils/examples.py showing in the `internals` method how to obtain the document (and therefore the dom tree), but is this the best way to go or would a regex based approach (find lines, remove them) be a lot easier? Working with the tree would also involve the conversion tree → document and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a nice solution for both problems. First, the `core.py` file in the `docutils` distribution shows how to obtain the doctree and how to write it (using a html writer for instance), see `publish_from_doctree` and `publish_doctree`. Then, there is `docutils.nodes.SparseNodeVisitor` which one can subclass and overwrite methods like `visit_field` to manipulate the document tree in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that can do this for you. See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/links.html

Comment: Sorry, the question was not precise enough. I know how to convert rst to html, I'd like to get into possession of my `tags` line and remove ot before rendering. But I think studying the source of Nabu is maybe the thing that closest brings me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In not too ancient Docutils, custom docinfo fields get the key as class value:

```
    <docinfo>
        <author>
            Me
        <field classes="tags">
            <field_name>
                tags
            <field_body>
                <paragraph>
                    foo, bar
```

If the class value is unique, you may use the [strip-elements-with-classes](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#strip-elements-with-classes) configuration setting to remove it. (Warning: all elements containing the same class value will be removed, too, the remaining doctree may be invalid...)

Alternatively, you may use a CSS rule (or LaTeX preamble code) to prevent displaying the "tag" field.

The extraction (and a more failproof suppression) could be achieved in a *Docutils transform*.
https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/peps/pep-0258.html#transformer
https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/api/transforms.html

Unfortunately, the Docutils documentation has no guide for creating and using custom transforms. However, the `docutils/transforms/*.py` sources provide examples for extracting info from the doctree and moving/deleting/modifying nodes.